# Mapping a unidirectional OneToMany association on a wrapper object using JPA

Tags: jpa

I am converting Hibernate configuration over to using JPA.  The current configuration has an AlertPref class (ALERT_PREF table) with a collection of Long types that are primary key values from the ALERT_CATEGORY table.  There is an ALERT_PREF_CATEGORY junction table that joins the two.  I could setup this relationship in JPA by defining the junction table as an Entity class and having a collection of AlertPrefCategory objects instead of Long IDs in the AlertPref class, but I want to avoid this if possible, and instead setup a uni-directional mapping from AlertPref to the Long IDs.  Some of the legacy code uses the IDs, and it would be difficult to change this code.

Here's the current class tag in the Hibernate config, which works fine:

```
<class name="AlertPref" table="ALERT_PREF">
    <id name="alertPrefId" column="ALERT_PREF_ID" type="long">
        <generator class="hilo">
            <param name="max_lo">100</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="userId" column="USER_ID" type="string"
        not-null="true" />

    <set name="excludedCategoryIds" table="ALERT_PREF_CATEGORY" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
        <key column="ALERT_PREF_ID" />
        <element column="EXCLUDED_CATEGORY_ID" type="long" />
    </set>

</class>
```

Here is what I tried to use in JPA, but it is throwing the exception "Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: AlertPref.excludedCategoryIds[java.lang.Long]"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALERT_PREF")
public class AlertPref {
    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "table_gen", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "table_gen")
    @Column(name = "ALERT_PREF_ID")
    private long alertPrefId;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "ALERT_PREF_CATEGORY", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ALERT_PREF_ID"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EXCLUDED_CATEGORY_ID"))
    private Set<Long> excludedCategoryIds;

    /**
     * @return Returns the alertPrefId.
     */
    public long getAlertPrefId() {
        return alertPrefId;
    }

    /**
     * @param alertPrefId
     *            The alertPrefId to set.
     */
    public void setAlertPrefId(long alertPrefId) {
        this.alertPrefId = alertPrefId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the userId.
     */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId
     *            The userId to set.
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the excludedCategoryIds
     */
    public Set<Long> getExcludedCategoryIds() {
        return excludedCategoryIds;
    }

    /**
     * @param excludedCategoryIds the excludedCategoryIds to set
     */
    public void setExcludedCategoryIds(Set<Long> excludedCategoryIds) {
        this.excludedCategoryIds = excludedCategoryIds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the ElementCollection and CollectionTable annotations, as explained in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-ofvalues).

Comment: I assume that if I want to do a cascade operation, then I would need to define an Entity to represent the junction table - is that correct?

Comment: No. A collection containing basic types or embedded components has the same life-cycle as the entity holding it. So, creating an AlertPref containing IDs will create the rows in the join table. Modifying the set will modify the rows accordingly. And removing the entity will remove the rows in the join table.

Comment: How can I notate a cascade and orphan removal?  These aren't an option on ElementCollection or CollectionTable.  If I delete an AlertPref column, I want any columns in AlertPrefCategory referencing the AlertPref to be deleted to maintain referential integrity.

Comment: I don't follow you. AlertPrefCategory doesn't reference AlertPref. The join table references AlertPref. And as I said, removing an AlertPref will remove all the rows in the join table that reference this AlertPref.

Comment: I think I understand... what is the point of cascade and orphanremoval settings then - does this not need to be specified in JPA?  My thinking was that this had to be specifically set for the rows in the join table (ALERT_PREF_CATEGORY) to be deleted when the rows in ALERT_PREF are deleted.

Comment: Suppose you have a one-to-many between a car and its wheels, using a join table. removing a wheel from the set of wheels normally just removes the row in the join table. But the wheel continues to exist in its own table. It's just not attached to any car anymore. If you set orphanRemoval to true on the wheels set in the car entity, removing a wheel from the set of wheels will not just remove the link between the car and the wheel, but also remove the wheel from its own table, because it becomes orphan : it doesn't have its parent car anymore.